# how to run Firebase listener on the main thread in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public class FirebaseNodeEntryGenerator {

  static String nextKey ="";

  static String keyGenerator{
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = firebaseDatabase.getReference(databaseReference);
    databaseReference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


             nextKey = "something";
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
     });



        return nextKey; 
    }

}
```

Basically, what i am trying to do is to create static method to generate some key based on the data from firebase database and return the generated key.

What I have problem with is that when i run the code, the method "keyGenerator" returns null for the "nextKey" because the "return nextKey" is called before the "nextKey = someKey" in the "onDataChange(Datasnapshot dataSnapshot)"

How can I make sure that the "nextKey = something" in the "onDataChange(Datasnapshot dataSnapshot)" is called before the "return nextKey"?

Comment: You want the method to be syncronous, but firebase listeners are not. You could pass a callback to be executed inside onDataChange method and make keyGenerator returning void

Comment: but i should return String from the method

Comment: You can't do that, since Firebase is a real time database and it is based in listeners. I'm afraid you have to change the approach.

Comment: Or you can make a busy waiting: `while (nextKey.isEmpty()) { //Do nothing };`. But it is a mess.

Comment: then is there any way to change the value of a variable in another class from the method?

Comment: I am thinking passing variable and change it in the method

Comment: Put more code where are you using this class. while `return nextKey` the variable has only "" value

Comment: I have to check the case if variable is not initialized and wait for a callback